# How to use chrome.printerProvider

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

### I need to control the printer by specific pdf file in some reason, thus I wanna using a chrome extension to solve it.

However, I found `chrome print.provider`, these APIs provide some events, but I assumed when the user press `ctrl+P` will trigger below event, but in fact, it does nothing happens.

---

```
chrome.printerProvider.onGetPrintersRequested.addListener(function(printerInfo) {
  console.log("onGetPrintersRequested", printerInfo);
});

chrome.printerProvider.onPrintRequested.addListener(function(printJob, resultCallback) {
  console.log("onPrintRequested ...", printJob);
});

chrome.printerProvider.onGetCapabilityRequested.addListener(function(printerId,resultCallback) {
  console.log("onGetCapabilityRequested ...", printerId);
});
```

---

What I misunderstand those events or I type the wrong callback function, is there has any good point to solve it, I found lots of people discuss this question before, but none of the proper answer I excepted.

Comment: The purpose of this API is to add a new virtual printer controlled by the extension. See also [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10257301)

Comment: Is that mean I need to add a virtual printer manually, or something else?
I sure I inspect the background console, but it didn't console anything :(

Comment: So far it's not clear what your ultimate goal is and I'm not sure this API would help you.

Comment: Simply say, I would like to get the ```printJob``` while the user ```print (Ctrl+P)``` the form, but I use the above APIs, it seems like did not trigger any of events.

Comment: Thinking logically, onGetPrintersRequested is probably called just once when the extension is started or installed, and the other events like onPrintRequested are triggered **only** on your extension's virtual printer.